# How to use bnd directives from maven-bundle-plugin?

Tags: maven, osgi, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

How can I use bnd directives instruction from maven-bundle-plugin? bnd directives are starting with a '-' character, and this is an invalid xml tag:

```
<-foo>bar</-foo>
```

I have checked the [official page](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) for maven-bundle-plugin, and they said that it should start with a '-' character as well:

> Directives - Any instruction starting with a '-' character is considered to be a directive that informs BND to perform some special processing and is not copied to the manifest.

The [bundle goal description](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/felix/releases/maven-bundle-plugin-2.3.7/doc/site/bundle-mojo.html) doesn't seem to have this information as well.
 to perform some special processing and is not copied to the manifest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the '-' character with '_' character. This will work:

```
<_foo>bar</_foo>
```

It is actually vaguely described in the [FAQ](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-bundle-plugin-faq.html) page:

> (this is <_exportcontents> in the POM because a tag can't start with '-')

This [improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-218) also can be found in their issue tracker.

Answer (score 5):

There is an alternative way to define the bnd instructions with less xml clutter:

Configure the plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <_include>-osgi.bnd</_include>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and provide a file (here: osgi.bnd) with the instructions, e.g.

```
 Import-Package: !javax.servlet,\
  !org.apache.avalon.framework.logger,\
  org.apache.commons.collections;version="[1.0,2)",\
  org.apache.commons.collections.comparators;version="[1.0,2)",\
  org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue;version="[1.0,2)",\
  org.apache.commons.collections.list;version="[1.0,2)",\
  org.apache.commons.collections.set;version="[1.0,2)",\
  !org.apache.log,\
  !org.apache.log4j,\
  *
 Export-Package: *
```

Remark: There **is** a minus sign in the _include tag before the filename!

A real life example can be found here:

[pom.xml file](https://github.com/evandor/skysail-bundled-libraries/blob/master/skysail.bundles.beanutils/pom.xml) and [osgi.bnd file](https://github.com/evandor/skysail-bundled-libraries/blob/master/skysail.bundles.beanutils/osgi.bnd).

Comment: Actually I'm using this now. The problem was, the -include itself is a bnd directive. Hence the question. Upped as it is helpful.